# Dojo Cross-Domain - Access is denied

Tags: dojo, cross-domain

I've got an issue when trying to use dojotoolkit cross domain.

I'm setting the headers in apache `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` which allows for it to work fine in all browsers except for IE8 and IE9. Where I get 'Access is denied' messages.

Such as

```
Line: 711
Character: 3
Code: 0
Error Message: Access is denied.

URL: http://remote.site.net/includes/dojotoolkit/dojo/_base/xhr.js
```

Can anyone spread any light on this?

Answer (score 4):

Internet Explorer 8 and 9 [does not support CORS via `XMLHttpRequest`](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors), but via proprietary [`XDomainRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28VS.85%29.aspx). Unfortunately, Dōjō does not take this into consideration and attempts to load a cross-domain resource via `XHR`, which ends with the *Access is denied* error.

Fortunately, Dōjō provides powerful [`dojo/request/registry`](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/request/registry), that allows you modify this behavior:

Define *XDomainRequest provider* that employs `XDomainRequest` to obtain a resource:

```
function xdr(url, options) {
    var def = new Deferred();
    var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
    if (xdr) {
        xdr.onload = function(e) {
            def.resolve(xdr.responseText);
        }
        xdr.open(options.method, url);
        xdr.send();
        return def;
    }
    def.reject(new Error('XDomainRequest not supported.'));
    return def;
}
```

Then define `corsProvider` that calls `XHR` or `XDR` depending on the browser:

```
function corsProvider(url, options) {
    if(window.XDomainRequest) {
        return xdr(url, options);
    }
    return xhr(url, options);
}
```

Register `corsProvider` to handle cross-domain requests:

```
var url = "http://cors-test.appspot.com/test";
var handle = request.register(url, corsProvider);
```

Now requesting a cross-domain resource should work in IE too:

```
request.get(url).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/LZZhs/

This applies for Dōjō 1.8+, because of `dojo/request`. If you need the same for `dojo/_base/xhr` there is `dojox.io.xhrPlugins`, but I have no experience with it. Anyway, it should be quite straightforward to implement the aforementioned via `dojo/aspect` for legacy Dōjō versions.

Comment: How does this change with dojo iframeRequest?

Answer (score 0):

IE8 and IE9 typically don't play very nicely with this stuff unless you start using their separate XDomainRequest objects.  What are you using to launch the request?

See also these other SO questions which deal with much of this:

- [CORS with jQuery and XDomainRequest in IE8/9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487216/cors-with-jquery-and-xdomainrequest-in-ie8-9)
- [cross-origin header in IE8/IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652364/cross-origin-header-in-ie8-ie9)